# File not found -- Android

Tags: android, file-io

I have created a file in the main activity as:

```
        File file = new File("library.xml");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream libXml = openFileOutput("library.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        libXml.write("[Some XML Data]");
```

Now I have created a **static** method in a class named `DataSource` and in this class I am trying to read from the file I just have created as:

```
        File file = new File("library.xml");
        Document data = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
```

But it raises an exception on the second line saying file not found...!
What could be wrong?

Comment: where is your files placed in project hierarchy??

Comment: Both files are in package's root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the above code in the question does not even creates a file, and raises permission denial exception, as it tries to create the file in root folder of android which is not permitted. So I just rewrite the above lines as:

```
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"library.xml");
```

for both write and then for read. It created my file in `/data/data/com.myapplication/files/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file to store in internal memory/storage, try the below code

**To Write**,

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

**To Read**,

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
int value=fis.read()
fis.close();
```

Have a look at android [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: But i want the file to be stored in the internal memory rather than sdcard.